Image upload with docker changes app.php makes docker won't run
Image upload with docker changes app.php causes Docker to not run.
I am new in Docker. I'm studying CRUD and the frontend is React and backend is Laravel.
Docker compose runs nginx, mysql, php-fpm.
In this app. I can post text and numbers at mysql table, but I'm having problem with image post. I can store image file name at mysql table, however the images won't saved at public/images directory.
I am using the following:
use Intervention\Image\ImageManager;
use Intervention\Image\Drivers\Imagick\Driver;

I am always getting this:

production.ERROR: Class "Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic" not found {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Class "Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic" not found at /var/www/app/Http/Controllers/ProductController.php:47)

package.json:
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.3",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.14",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
        "intervention/image": "^3.9",
        "jorijn/laravel-security-checker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/framework": "^11.0",
        "laravel/passport": "^12.3",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^4.0",
        "laravel/slack-notification-channel": "^3.2",
        "laravel/socialite": "^5.15",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
        "nesbot/carbon": "^3.4",
        "opcodesio/log-viewer": "^3.10",
        "predis/predis": "^2.2",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^6.9"
    },

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManager;
use Intervention\Image\Drivers\Imagick\Driver;
    


            $manager = new ImageManager(new Driver());
            $imageFields = ['image_1', 'image_2', 'image_3'];
            $images = [];

            foreach ($imageFields as $imageField) {
                if ($request->hasFile($imageField)) {
                    $image = $request->file($imageField);
                    $imageName = time() . '_' . uniqid() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
                    $originalPath = public_path('images');
                    $resizedPath = public_path('images/resized');

                    // Create and resize the image
                    $img = $manager->read($image->path());
                    $img->resize(350, null, function ($constraint) {
                        $constraint->aspectRatio();
                        $constraint->upsize();
                    });

                    // Save original and resized images
                    $img->save($originalPath . '/' . $imageName);
                    $img->resize(100, 100)->save($resizedPath . '/' . $imageName);

                    // Store image paths in the array
                    $images[$imageField] = [
                        'name' => $imageName,
                        'path' => 'images/' . $imageName,
                        'resized_path' => 'images/resized/' . $imageName,
                    ];

                    // Add image data to productData for database storage
                    $productData[$imageField] = $imageName;
                }
            }

            // Create the product record in the database
            $product = Product::create($productData);

            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'success',
                'message' => 'Product added successfully!',
                'data' => $product,
                'images' => $images
            ], 201);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Catch unexpected exceptions and return error message
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'An unexpected error occurred!',
                'error_detail' => $e->getMessage()
            ], 500);
        }
        

I tried to find soluiton and i see many documents talks about app.php, but once I add this lines at config/app.php Docker compose won't build, and the composer update also wont run.
If I remove these two lines I can docker compose build and composer update.
Could someone teach me the solution please?
app.php
'providers' => [
    ...
    Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
],

'aliases' => [
    ...
    'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,
],


